# A mistery in the documentation of the StreamDensityPlot command, and Is Abs' the same as Sign?

Tags: vector-calculus

I was trying to decipher the documentation example

```
StreamDensityPlot[{{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, 
  Log[Norm[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}] + 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", StreamStyle -> Black, 
 StreamPoints -> Medium, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

I guessed wrongly, before checking,  that that means

```
sf = Log[Norm[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}] + 1];
StreamDensityPlot[{{D[sf, x], D[sf, y]}, sf}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
D[sf, x] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}
```

Anyway, the output of my wrong guess contains Abs' , the meaning of which I could not find, and also a range error

```
General::ivar: -3. is not a valid variable
```

I removed  the  problems with a simpler example  that works

```
sf = x^2 + y^2;
StreamDensityPlot[{{2 x, 2 y}, sf}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

I tried then to have Mathematica compute alone the derivatives (I bought it precisely to avoid computing alone  derivatives :)

```
sf = x^2 + y^2; D[sf, x]
StreamDensityPlot[{{D[sf, x], D[sf, y]}, sf}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

the derivative is fine :), but the range error reappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Ok ?

```
sf = Log[Norm[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}] + 1] /. Abs -> Identity;
Grad[sf, {x, y}]
StreamDensityPlot[Grad[sf, {x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
D[sf, x] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}
```

Comment: I would use ComplexExpand instead of the replacement `Abs -> Identity`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks!